# Including a response header with res.redirect

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

A Node.js app needs to:

1.) receive data from another serve that calls `/some_endpoint`,
2.) process the data it receives to create a String result `jwtString`,
3.) redirect the user to the root `/` url of the AngularJS app while passing the `jwtString` as a `res.header` included inside the `res.redirect`.

**What specific changes need to be made to the Node.js routing code below in order for the `_jwt` header to be successfully passed from the Node.js app to the client AngularJS at at `/`?**

```
app.get('/some_endpoint', function(req, res) {
    //Process data from another server that was redirected here.
    //then send the result of that processing in jwtString while 
    //redirecting user to the root url of the Angular app that
    //is served by this Node.js instance.
    res.setHeader('_jwt', jwtString);
    res.redirect('/');
});

app.get('*', function(req, res) {
    var queryData = url.parse(req.url, true);
    console.log('in get *, queryData is: ');console.log(queryData);
    res.sendfile('./public/index.html'); // load the single view file (angular will handle the front-end)
});
```

When I run the code above, I cannot seem to find the `_jwt` header in the Network tab of the FireFox developer tools.

Comment: HTTP does not have any way to tell the browser to pass a header along with the redirect request.  Consider using the querystring instead (which seems to be what you want)

Comment: @SLaks This is a JWT (token) which contains the username, etc.  I thought sending that information in the querystring would be a security risk.

Comment: @SLaks Can I send it in a cookie instead?

Comment: Sending a cookie works.  However, it would be nice to send it as a header.

Comment: There is no substantial difference between sending it in the querystring as opposed to any other part of the request.  If it's sensitive, you should keep it on the server only.

Comment: what about call the rest endpoint to get the token, and do the redirect from angular controller?

Comment: @fdam This node instance should have no memory of the token.  The node.js instance gets the token from the Angular client, and then looks up the user in a separate Redis server/cluster, so that the app can include as many cloned Node.js servers as necessary.